# CUDA global static data alternative?

Tags: memory-management, runtime, constants, cuda

I'm building a toolkit that offers different algorithms in CUDA. However, many of these algorithms use static constant global data that will be used by all threads, declared this way for example:

```
static __device__ __constant__ real buf[MAX_NB];
```

My problem is that if I include all the .cuh files in the library, when the library will be instantiated all this memory will be allocated on the device, even though the user might want to use only one of these algorithms. Is there any any way around this? Will I absolutely have to use the typical dynamically allocated memory?

I want the fastest constant memory possible that can be used by all threads at runtime. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: it will be allocated per a single kernel launch.  if kernel doesnt reference the constant memory, it wont be allocated.

Comment: If you go with the dynamically allocated global memory, can you use shared memory to improve your memory access times? (also, I use constant in my programs, but without static device... is there a difference?)

Comment: @aaa: that doesn't make a lot of sense to me, can you explain or point to a reference? if it's not a compiler optimization, does it allocate at kernel launch, or when the memory is referenced? does that mean cudaMemcpyToSymbol calls are queued and only executed when the data is needed?

Comment: @jmi as far as i know, constant memory is essentially static to compile unit. so you only have to deal with constatnt limits on TU level, not across program as a whole. I should have explained better, my bad. and yes, cudaMemcpyToSymbol are queued in a stream. http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=30269&pid=170031&start=&st=#entry170031

Comment: @aaa No, not really making sense yet. First, I assume from the question we're setting the constant during runtime from the host, hence cudaMemcpyToSymbol. Of course these calls are async launches... the question is, does the transfer happen if no kernel references the memory later? If yes, then the memory CAN NOT BE allocated per single kernel launch. Second, what? "compile unit"? TU? Third, from the link, what does it mean "the constants are "embedded in the executable"?

Comment: @jmi Ok, let me start over.  If you take one .cu file file, all constant memory is "private" to that compilation unit.  Its not accessible from other .cu files, nor does it take up the constant memory of another file.  TU - Translation unit.  By reference i meant visibility, not actual memory reference - very bad choice of words.

Comment: @aaa Ok (I think). To be pedantic, there is a library built with many .cuh files. The user links the entire library, but only includes one of the header files. Then, only the constant memory from the included header file is allocated. Correct? Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: Actually, I haven't even built the library yet and I can say that this doesn't work. The static constant memory is allocated in all .cuh files, kernel launch or not.

Comment: Good news! aaa was right all along! It's just that instead of being in different .cuh files, they have to be in different .cu files! When the .cubin is generated and run, each .cu belongs to a different module. Therefore, cnstant memory is local to the source file in which it is declared. You can check out this post: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=185993. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the constant memory in a .cu file is allocated at launch (When the .cubin is generated and run, each .cu belongs to a different module)! Therefore, to use many different kernels that use constant memory, you have to divide them in .cu files as to not get a const memory overflow. The usual max is 64kb. Source: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=185993

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Do you mean to say that the constant memory defined in different .cu files will never be allocated at the same time during execution? Even if kernels from the are executing concurrently? Also, the thread you linked to says that the constant memory cache is 6k-8k in size. So what's with the 64kb limit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into texture memory? I believe it is tricky but that it can be quite fast and can be allocated dynamically.

If you can't use textures, I've been brainstorming and the only thing I can think of for constant is to allocate a single constant array... some amount that is hopefully less than /all/ of the constants in /all/ of the headers, but big enough for what anyone would need in a maximal use case. Then you can load different values into this array for different needs.

(I'm assuming you've confirmed that allocating constant memory for the entire library is a problem. Is it insufficient space, or long initialization times, or what?)

Comment: you have to be careful not to use the same name for constatn memory across different .cu files - it causes funny runtime confusions.